# How to Filter multiple values for Where statement of SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

Can any help on the below Query in the where statement in T-SQL?

I have ID & Product fields in table,in where condition need to exclude the ID not in('11','22','33') only when for Product='c'

```
Select ID,Product from Supplier
where 1=1 and Product in('A','B','C')
```

The statment should present

```
and ID not in('11','22','33')
```

Expecting when the Product='C', exclude the ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
Select ID, Product from Supplier
where 1=1 and 
    ( Product in('A','B')
        OR ( Product = 'C' AND ID not in('11','22','33')) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use not exists

```
Select ID,Product from Supplier a
where 1=1 and Product in('A','B','C') and not exists 
(
  select 1 from supplier b where a.product=b.product and b.product='C' and
  b.ID in('11','22','33')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `not exists`

```
 select * from table t1
 where not exists ( select 1 from table t2 where t1.Product=t2.Product
                              and t2.Product='C'
                              and ID in('11','22','33')
                  )
  and Product in('A','B','C')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Very simple

```
SELECT * FROM Supplier WHERE Product !='c' OR ( Id NOT IN(11,22,33) AND Product= 'c')
```

Add your new condition.

```
SELECT * FROM Supplier WHERE (Product in ('a','b','c') and Product !='c' ) OR ( Id NOT IN(11,22,33) AND Product= 'c')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm expecting as below: 1)The Where statement it needs to Filter the Product in('A','B','C')//The statement should present
2)One more condition,it only specific when Product=C & exclude the ID not in('11','22','33').

Comment: Please replace query                                                                                                      SELECT * FROM Supplier WHERE (Product in ('a','b','c') and Product !='c' ) OR ( Id NOT IN(11,22,33) AND Product= 'c')